# Progress cell height is equal to table body height

Tags: height, progress, tabulator

What value must be changed in css or Tabulator options to encourage Tabulator to calculate reasonable values for the cell heights when using progress bars? By cell height, I mean div class='tabulator-cell' of course.

I have tried setting table height in Tabulator options to integers, strings like 200px, 200%, none work (all work to set the table height but none change the way the cell height is calculated).

Tabulator 5.5.2, 5.5, 5.2 fresh installs and copy paste examples of progress yields cell heights equal to table height less 56px (for the header surely), each row completely filling the available visible height. The cell elements have a manually set style for height that is exactly the height of the table less 56px. When I change the height of the table, the cells and spans change to maintain h = table h - 56px.

When using the 5.2 markup and script with 4.2 js library and css, the height is have a manually set style for height that is reasonable (around 22 24px) and looks fine.

When remove from each example the formatter:progress, row heights become reasonable values (22 to 26px).

The manually set styles are evidently calculated by Tabulator progress feature and seem out of my control.

I have looked into the Tabulator code but it's a bit heavy for me.

Previous bugs filed (and closed) on progress bar height are not relevant because submitters found they had open tags. I've copy pasted examples exactly and do not find any open tags.

Apologies for missing something that perhaps others haven't.

Absolutely outstanding library and infrastructure!

Chrome 117.0.5938.149 (Official Build) (arm64)
Safari 16.6
Mac OS 13.6

Comment: Using the same sample files, with formatter:progress, every cell and every item inside each cell has a inline height of 2.51658e7px.

When I manually disable these heights in devtools, display becomes normal.

So it's clearly the math going haywire.

I'd like to fix it.

.../formatters/progress.js  mentions height twice, setting to 100%, but inline style height in the resulting html is a large number. I am willing to hunt around or brutally hack. For example, I edited the 100%s to 22px but no change resulted.

Any suggestions?